# Python Pandoc Subprocess Not Printing STDOUT When Exception Occurs

Tags: python, exception, subprocess, pandoc

I'm trying to run a process with subprocess and print its entire output if and only if an exception occurs.

### Where I was before:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run(
        command,
        capture_output=True,
        check=True,
        text=True,
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print(error.output)
```

This did not work.

Output when subprocess.CalledProcessError occurs:

```
b''
```

Replacing capture_output with stdout=subprocess.PIPE resulted in the output of everything regardless whether an exception occurred or not, error.output was still empty.

### So I experimented:

#### This prints everything I would see if I executed the command in the command-line.

```
subprocess.run(
    command,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
)
```

#### This prints out nothing.

```
proc = subprocess.run(
    command,
    capture_output=True,
)
print(proc.stdout.decode())
```

I also tried subprocess.check_output() which to my information does the same as subprocess.run() with the flags I set in the first code snippet.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

### Addendum

```
import subprocess

command = ['pandoc', 'file']

try:
    proc = subprocess.run(
        command,
        capture_output=True,
        check=True,
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print('Exception:')
    print(error.output)
```

This is an MWE with the specific process I want to run ([pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc))

### Output

```
$ pandoc file
pandoc: file: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

$ ./samplecode.py
Exception:
b''
```

So the exception gets triggered, but the output object is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the error message is present in error.stderr and not in error.output. I tried your example (with a ls of non-existent file) :

```
import subprocess

command = ['ls', 'file']

try:
    proc = subprocess.run(
        command,
        check=True,
        capture_output=True,
        text=True
    )
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
    print('Exception:')
    print('output : ' + error.output)
    print('stderr : ' + error.stderr)
```

The output is the following :

```
Exception:
output : 
stderr : ls: file: No such file or directory
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, my try-except block works. It's just not printing anything using the output object.

Comment: Hi, Could you add more details  with code example to see where the problem is ? If you have some output from your code also ? Thx.

Comment: Thank you! Dunno why I haven't thought about this before.

Comment: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'capture_output'

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're meaning to run is `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`. This should print the relevant error code to the standard console error output.

Example:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['ls', 'myfile.txt'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
(output,error) = process.communicate()
if error:
    print error
```